# Filtering is supported only on partition keys of type string Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hive-partitions

We recently started facing issues with spark 2.4.4 with hive 1.2.1 version.

when we are trying to read data from a table which is partition by string type columns

```
spark.sql("select count(*) from table where #conditions");

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Caught Hive MetaException attempting to get partition metadata by filter from Hive. You can set the Spark configuration setting spark.sql.hive.manageFilesourcePartitions to false to work around this problem, however this will result in degraded performance. Please report a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_13.getPartitionsByFilter(HiveShim.scala:772)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getPartitionsByFilter$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:693)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getPartitionsByFilter$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:691)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:226)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.getPartitionsByFilter(HiveClientImpl.scala:691)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$listPartitionsByFilter$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:1221)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$listPartitionsByFilter$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:1214)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.listPartitionsByFilter(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:1214)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.listPartitionsByFilter(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listPartitionsByFilter(SessionCatalog.scala:962)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.rawPartitions$lzycompute(HiveTableScanExec.scala:174)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.rawPartitions(HiveTableScanExec.scala:166)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec$$anonfun$11.apply(HiveTableScanExec.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec$$anonfun$11.apply(HiveTableScanExec.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withDummyCallSite(Utils.scala:2470)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec.doExecute(HiveTableScanExec.scala:191)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:391)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:627)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
  ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: Filtering is supported only on partition keys of type string
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_13.getPartitionsByFilter(HiveShim.scala:759)
  ... 121 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: Filtering is supported only on partition keys of type string
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_by_filter_result$get_partitions_by_filter_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_by_filter_result$get_partitions_by_filter_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_by_filter_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
  at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_partitions_by_filter(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:2216)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_partitions_by_filter(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:2200)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.listPartitionsByFilter(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1103)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:156)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.listPartitionsByFilter(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getPartitionsByFilter(Hive.java:2254)
  ... 126 more
```

I have tried multiple things to fix the issues
first by disabling `spark.sql.hive.manageFilesourcePartitions=false` as mentioned in the log
and also disabling `hive.metastore.try.direct.sql=false` (hive-site.xml)

and also looked in the [spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/client/HiveShim.scala) and disabled hive.metastore.try.direct.sql=false ... somehow the exception still remains same.

I'm I doing anything wrong?.

I have checked mulitple threads [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054700/spark-2-3-to-spark-2-4-upgrade-problems-reading-hive-partitioned-tables) ,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372962/filtering-a-spark-partitioned-table-is-not-working-in-pyspark) and [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18680).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of debugging and trying multiple things as mentioned in the question. I finally changed partition column types to `string` (some of the partition columns are `int` type before) after column type change to `string` query seems to be working fine.

> string.spark.sql("select count(*) from table where #conditions");